# Erro ao tentar atualizar um post no WordPress usando o plugin WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, angular

> Olá, sou novo com WordPress e preciso (pra ontem) resolver esse problema. **Help!**

Estou criando uma integração simples em Angular 2 (v6+) que acessa a api gerada pelo plugin [WP REST API](https://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/) e o json que estou enviando está com os seguintes dados:

```
{
   "date":"2018-09-09T17:13:50",
   "date_gmt":"2018-09-09T17:13:50",
   "slug":"4-duvidas-respondidas-sobre-presenca-digital",
   "status":"publish",
   "password":null,
   "title":"4 dúvidas respondidas sobre presença digital",
   "content":"<p>Search Engine Optimization (SEO), Inbound Marketing, Google Ads, site responsivo… Todos esses termos são conceitos comuns no universo do marketing digital. No entanto, médicos que buscam inovar a sua forma de captar novos pacientes por meio da internet podem encontrar dificuldades para compreender o que tais nomenclaturas representam – assim como o termo “nevos” pode gerar estranhamento em profissionais de comunicação digital.</p>\n<p>Neste artigo, levantamos as principais dúvidas apontadas por nossos clientes com relação à presença digital de profissionais de saúde. Iremos falar para aqueles que já têm atuado de alguma forma na internet, com o objetivo de gerar mais oportunidades para a clínica ou consultório médico.</p>\n<p>Caso você ainda não use a internet com esse fim, mas tem planos de iniciar a sua presença digital, este artigo também será importante para clarear possíveis sombras que possam prejudicar a sua atuação em <a class=\"aalmanual\" title=\"\" href=\"http://blog.imedicina.com.br/marketing-medico\" target=\"_self\">marketing médico</a>. Vamos lá!</p>\n",
   "author":1,
   "excerpt":"<p>Search Engine Optimization (SEO), Inbound Marketing, Google Ads, site responsivo… Todos esses termos são conceitos comuns no universo do marketing digital. No entanto, médicos que buscam inovar a sua forma de captar novos pacientes por meio da internet podem encontrar dificuldades para compreender o que tais nomenclaturas representam – assim como o termo “nevos” pode &hellip; </p>\n<p class=\"link-more\"><a href=\"http://localhost/imedicina-test/2018/09/09/4-duvidas-respondidas-sobre-presenca-digital/\" class=\"more-link\">Continue reading<span class=\"screen-reader-text\"> &#8220;4 dúvidas respondidas sobre presença digital&#8221;</span></a></p>\n",
   "comment_status":"open",
   "format":"standard",
   "meta":[],
   "sticky":false,
   "template":"",
   "categories":[1],
   "tags":[],
   "liveblog_likes":0
}
```

No header estou enviando corretamente o Header abaixo:

```
{ 
    header : {
        Authorization: " o token aqui "
    }
}
```

Mas quando eu envio para a rota conforme a api eu recebo a mensagem abaixo:

```
{
    code: "rest_cannot_edit", 
    message: "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post.", 
    data: {
        status: 401
    }
}
```

Como posso fazer para conseguir atualizar o post de fora do WordPress utilizando Angular 2 (v6+)

Comment: pelo postman ou tecnologia parecida funciona?

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei os problemas mais comuns são: (1) o usuário não ter permissão `edit_posts` e (2) o servidor (Apache, Nginx, etc...) [tira fora o cabeçalho `Authorization`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36499422/1284458).

Comment: achei o problema, a partir do que o @EduardoVargas falou que eu cheguei na solução

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei o problema. Quando li novamente a documentação da primeira vez eu não estava me atentando aos detalhes e nela diz que para conseguir fazer todos os processos o plugin WP REST API depende do plugin WP API Basic Auth e eu não tinha instalado ele. Usando o plugin eu consigo enviar um header assim:

```
public usuario = { login: 'admin', senha : '@teste12345' };

public updatePost(post) {

    let token = btoa(this.usuario.login + ':' + this.usuario.senha);

    let header = { 
        header : {
            Authorization: "Basic " + token;
        }
    }

    // resto da implementação aqui

}
```

Meu maior problema é que eu estava usando um plugin chamado jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api e achava que o token que devia ser enviado ali era o que ele retornava.